# How to check how many blocks of polkadot node are synced?

Tags: polkadot, nodes

I've started the syncing of polkadot node and I want to check how many blocks have synced can anyone tell me how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Drew's answer...

You should see something like this when syncing:

```sh
2022-07-22 19:38:12 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 91.7 bps, target=#11280082 (50 peers), best: #7467984 (0x2517…6b44), finalized #7467520 (0x7ec6…add8), ⬇ 106.0kiB/s ⬆ 37.1kiB/s
```

Notice the **target** and **finalized** block numbers.

In my example, I am still far from the target (which is when I am fully synced).

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can use PolkadotJS or cURL to query that info from the RPC.
For example the last head:

```bash
curl -sS -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "chain_getHeader"}' http://localhost:9933/ | jq '.result.number' -r
```

which prints hex. PolkadotJS is more convenient, see [getHeader](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#getheaderhash-blockhash-header) and [getFinalizedHead](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#getfinalizedhead-blockhash).

Answer (score 0):

On the execution of your chain's node, you should see logs like:

```
2022-08-30 18:29:22.545  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (2 peers), best: #18 (0x43b6…2bc0), finalized #17 (0xcbf3…7bac), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

This tells you that you have synced 18 blocks, 17 of which are finalized.